# Javascript or Jquery to detect page refresh and redirect to error page - avoid duplicate data submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tried jQuery to redirect to error page when jsp page is refreshed using F5 or 
browser refresh button with the following :

```
function confirmExit() {
   alert("exiting");
   window.location.href='index.html';
   return true;
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

The above code gives alert when page refreshed, but `window.onbeforeunload`  also 
alerts when save button is pressed and page is not redirected and duplicate data is submitted. Im doing this to avoid duplicate data submission on refresh. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a relocate with the `onbeforeunload` event. The browser simply won't allow it, because of security reasons. (Eg, I could keep you on my page forever.)

The only thing you can really do with `onbeforeupload` is ask the user if he's sure if you wants to exit.

You need to accept that there is little you can do in preventing a user to make an HTTP request, by refreshing or whatever means. Instead you need solve this on the server side, redirecting the browser if the same request is made twice.

---

To answer your question about the save button (even though it probably isn't relevant any more).

```
var saved = false;

function confirmExit() {
   if (saved) return;
   return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

document.getElementById('#save').onclick = function() {
   saved = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So do you think theres no other way we can detect a browser refresh and redirect to error page other than Server side handling of the issue ?

Comment: No you can't prevent a user from refreshing. That is outside the scope of the web application. The simplest way to solve this would be to set a cookie and check the cookie on the server. If it exists, do a 301 redirect to the error page.

Comment: @taurivalor Please accept the answer, if you feel that your question has been answered.